# ggpubr ggbarplot plotted with bizarre xvalues

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have the following code using the CSV below

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggsci)
df = read.csv2("file.csv", row.names=1)
# Copy df
df2 = df
# Convert the cyl variable to a factor
df2$perc <- as.factor(df2$perc)
# Add the name colums
df2$name <- rownames(df)
ggbarplot(df2, x = "name", y = "perc",
          fill = "role",               # change fill color by cyl
          color = "white",            # Set bar border colors to white
          palette = "npg",            # jco journal color palett. see ?ggpar
          sort.val = "asc",          # Sort the value in dscending order
          sort.by.groups = FALSE,     # Don't sort inside each group
          x.text.angle = 0,           # Rotate vertically x axis texts
          rotate = TRUE,
          label = TRUE, label.pos = "out",
          #label = TRUE, lab.pos = "in", lab.col = "white",
          width = 0.5
)
```

the CSV is :

```
genes;perc;role
GATA-3;7,9;confirmed in this cancer
CCDC74A;6,8;prognostic in this cancer
LINC00621;6,1;none
POLRMTP1;4,1;none
IGF2BP3;3,2;confirmed in this cancer
```

which produced this plot

[image]

There are two things I don't get here:

1) Why the x-axis tick of each bar correspond to the actual value plotted ? I mean why the x-axis isn't from 0 to 8, and should be in my opinion. I hope I explain correctly.

2) The label value seems unaligned with the y-thick. Am I missing an option here ?

Comment: For (1): is your x-variable a factor perhaps? Continuous x-scales work best with numerical data

Comment: True, the df2$perc <- as.numeric(df2$perc) fixed the problem (1)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I would probably not use `ggpubr` here. Staying in the ggplot syntax is often safer. And also arguably less code... 
(Also, don't use factors in this case, as user teunbrand commented)

**Two good options** for horizontal bars:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggstance)
library(ggsci)
```

**Option 1** - use coord_flip

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(fct_reorder(genes, perc), perc, fill = role)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = perc), hjust = 0) +
  scale_fill_npg() +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0,100)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top') +
  labs(x = 'gene', y = 'percent')
```

[image]

**option 2 - use the ggstance package**
I prefer option 2, because using ggstance allows for more flexible combination with other plots

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(perc, fct_reorder(genes, perc), fill = role)) +
  geom_colh() +
  geom_text(aes(label = perc), hjust = 0)+
  scale_fill_npg() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,100)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')+
  labs(x = 'gene', y = 'percent')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**data**

```
df2 <- read_delim("genes;perc;role
GATA-3;7,9;confirmed in this cancer
CCDC74A;6,8;prognostic in this cancer
LINC00621;6,1;none
POLRMTP1;4,1;none
IGF2BP3;3,2;confirmed in this cancer", ";") %>% rownames_to_column("name")
```

Comment: Thanks for the two options, these seems elegants.

Comment: Error in fct_reorder(genes, perc) : could not find function "fct_reorder". I have a tidy verse problem here. Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.0 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required

Comment: @BenoitB. maybe time to update your packages? fct_reorder has been around for quite a while ... If you cannot use this, use the classic `factor(x, levels = ...)` way